# What is the msvc .obj (COFF?) file format when using cl.exe with the /GL option?

Tags: c++, c, windows, linker, coff

According to msdn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)

> .obj files produced with /GL will not be available to such linker utilities as EDITBIN and DUMPBIN.

Is there any publically available specification on the .obj files generated when using /GL (To use, for example, if someone wanted to write a custom link.exe replacement)?

Tangentially related question: [How to determine the major compiler version from .obj files compiled with /GL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639518/how-to-determine-the-major-compiler-version-from-obj-files-compiled-with-gl)

Comment: This is from [Matt Pietrek's column in May 2002](http://web.archive.org/web/20021001164348/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/msdnmag/issues/02/05/default.asp) but AFAIK hasn't changed since: "*the IL used with LTCG is undocumented and subject to change from version to version of the compiler*".